# Weyl algebra acting on a polynomial ring

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, differential-operators, d-modules, groebner-bases

Let $\mathbb K$ be a characteristic-$0$ field, $R=\mathbb K[x_1,\ldots,
x_n]$ be a polynomial ring, and $W=\mathbb K[x_1,\ldots,x_n,\partial_1,\ldots \partial_n]$ be the Weyl
algebra. As usual $W$ acts on $R$ as,
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:1}
  x_i \bullet f=x_i f,\quad \partial_i \bullet f=\frac{\partial
    f}{\partial x_i},\quad \forall f \in R
\end{equation}
Let $\mathcal D=\{D_1, \ldots, D_k\}$ be a finite subset of $W$. Denote
$\mathcal D \bullet R$ be the $\mathbb K$-linear space,
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:2}
  \mathcal D \bullet R\equiv {\rm span}_{\mathbb K}\{ D_i \bullet f
|1\leq i\leq k,\ \forall f\in R\}
\end{equation}
The $\mathbb K$-linear quotient space $R/(\mathcal D \bullet R)$ is
the object of our interest. We want a practical way (1) to
calculate $\dim_{\mathbb K} R/(\mathcal D \bullet R)$, if it is finite,
 (2) to determine if a given polynomial $F\in R$ is in $(\mathcal D
   \bullet R)$ or not.

Note that if $D_i$'s contain no differential operator, i.e. if
$D_i\in R$, $1\leq i \leq k$, then both questions can be solved by
the (commutative) Gr\"obner basis computation of a polynomial
ideal. For the general case, is there a way to solve them by computing Gr\"obner
basis for an ideal of the Weyl algebra?

Comment: There is a filtration on the Weyl algebra such that the associated graded ring is just a polynomial algebra in $2n$ variables, and so I suspect that the non-commutative analogue of Groebner bases works out very nicely.  Have you had any luck doing computations when $|\mathcal D|=1$?

Comment: Gröbner bases work fine for the Weyl algebra, e.g. Macaulay2 has a good implementation. Also, do you really want $\mathcal{D}$ to be a *finite set*, or the *left ideal in $W$ generated by* that finite set?

Comment: Thanks Ketil! I tried Macaulay2: Consider the {\it right}-ideal I generated by $\mathcal D$. (Since Macaulay2 deals with left ideals, I used the antihomomorphism of $W$ to switch between the left/right). Let the $\{g_i\}$ be the Gr\"obner basis of $I$, by the division in $W$, $F=\sum_i g_i
\cdot q_i + O$. Act this relation on $R$, so $F=(O\bullet 1) +(
{\text polynomials\ in\ } \mathcal D\bullet
R)$. $(O\bullet 1)$ seems like ``normal form'' of $F$. However, I am not sure how to choose a good weight vector of $W$, so this division works for some cases but failed for others.

Comment: Keith, yes, I want $\mathcal D$ to be a finite set since for my problem, the context is that $D_i$'s are coming from some tangent vector fields of an affine variety.

Comment: In usual (commutative polynomial) Gröbner basis theory, one has a gradation and therefore filtration on the polynomial ring $R$, and an ideal $I$, so therefore $gr\ R$ acts on $init\ I := gr\ I$. A generating set for the latter ideal lifts to a set in $I$ that automatically generates, and gets called a Gröbner basis. In standard treatments $R$ and $gr\ R$ are identified, which is confusing when one wants to deal with situations like yours where the filtration doesn't come from a gradation (and $gr\ W \not\cong W$).

Comment: You start with "$W$ acts on $R$", i.e. $R = W/\langle (\partial_i)\rangle$. Then your module of interest is $R/\mathcal D\bullet R = W/\langle (\partial_i), \mathcal D\rangle$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Allen! I agree the module of interest is $W/\langle
(\partial_i), \mathcal D \rangle$. Then the difficulty is that
$\langle (\partial_i), \mathcal D \rangle$ is a "mixture" of left and
right ideals in $W$. Since for my case, to get $\langle (\partial_i),
\mathcal D \rangle$, I need to multiply $(\partial_i)$ by elements in
$W$ from left, while multiply $\mathcal D$ by elements in $W$ from
right.